# marionette serializeData no models in collection

Tags: coffeescript, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a Marionette and Handlebars setup for a single page app. I didn't start this project; it was first developed by someone else.

I managed to figure out stuff in other files, but I can't get to figure this one out.

So, I have models/order.coffee

```
Model = require './model'
Collection = require './collection'

module.exports = class OrderModel extends Model
  # This is the *real* orders model
  idAttribute: 'uid'
  defaults:
    title: 'some order'

module.exports = class Orders extends Collection
  model: OrderModel

  url: base_url+'history/'

  initialize: =>
    super
    @fetch()

  parse: (response) =>
    return response.objects
```

The `parse` is there because of how the backend returns data. `response.objects` contains a list of JSON objects from which models are created, that is `OrderModel` instances\

Next there is `views/SettingsOrderView.coffee`

```
template = require './templates/settings/orders'

module.exports = class SettingsOrdersView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    template: template
    events: 'click #back_to_options': 'goToOptions'

    serializeData: =>
        data = @.collection
        setTimeout (-> console.log(data.models)), 5000
        $.each data.models, (m_index, m) =>
            console.log(m)

        return {items: @.collection}
```

My problem is the in the template I do `{{#each items}}`, but they are instances of OrderModel, so they are useless in Handlebars. I need to make them as JSON objects, but for some reason (the `collection.fetch()` actually) does not populate `@.collection.models` in `serializeData`. After 5 seconds (as seen in `setTimeout`) the `data.models` is a list of exactly what I need, but the `each` is not executed because at that time `data.models` is an empty list.

As said, I need to JSONize the models, but are not available. How can I fix this ?

If you need other data, comment and I'll post it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rendering collections Marionette provides a CollectionView: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md

For a discussion on when to use a CollectionView or a ItemView for multiple items, see this excellent article:
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

To serialize a model, you can call model.toJSON() on the model. Or you could simply get single attributes with the get() function or by writing your own JSON method on the model and/or collection. In that case you could simply call that method on the collection.

But I guess your real problem is the call to fetch(). If I understand you correctly the models seem to be missing by the time you are trying to use them.
Backbone provides a success callback for this situation. This callback will be called, when the data is ready.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Now, I never used this by myself - using websockets and promises instead of backbones sync mechanism - but taking a peek at this article, this could be useful for your case:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/03/get-a-model-from-a-backbone-collection-without-knowing-if-the-collection-is-loaded/

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I removed the collection and used `success` callback on the model itself. It's a bit of a hack what I did here, but serves my purpose.